# Can I pass a condition to a method as parameter in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have 2 buttons doing the same function but in different condition.
there code is something like this.

```
private void button1_Click(){
// do function1

if(condition){
    ...decrement an integer
    //do function2
}
}


private void button2_Click(){
// do function1

if(another condition){
    ...increment an integer

    //do function2
}
}
```

Can I pass condition1 and condition2 and increment, decrement to a method ?

Comment: you could pass a lambda to your method and execute it or not

Comment: Yes you can... but can you elaborate the question? what kind of condition are you talking abt here? inc,dec can be passed, yes.

Comment: @Sharmi condition is greater than or less than.

Comment: @user1340443 May be you should take a look at a similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3324023/1278315 .May be that helps but i have not come across such a situation... :) esp. this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3324052/1278315  might help:)

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. But you are still limited in what you can do. Consider this

```
public void Foo(Action action, Func<Boolean> someCondition) {
    if (someCondition() == true) action();
}
```

Comment: Why write `if (condition() == true)` instead of simply `if (condition())`?

Comment: Personal preference, I consider it more readable. I also use condition() == false.

Comment: once the condition method is renamed,                                               using for example : `if(IsAvailable() == true) { // do something}`                              will add more *noise* than simplicity of reading.                                                               Compare with  `if(IsAvailable()) { // do something}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
    private void buttonClick()
    {
        DoSomething(condition ? true : false);
    }
    private void DoSomething(bool increment)
    {
        // do stuff

        if (increment)
            ++index;
        else
            --index;
    }
```

Comment: Why write `condition ? true : false` instead of simply `condition`?

Comment: `condition ? true : false` If you write code like that in my codebase, you shall be shot!

Answer (score 1):

Why not to extract duplicated code to methods?

```
private void Function1() 
{ 
   // do function1
}

private void Function2()
{
   // do function2
}

private void button1_Click()
{
   Function1() ;

   if(condition)
   {
       //...decrement an integer
       Function2();
   }
}

private void button2_Click()
{
  Function1();

  if(another condition)
  {
    //...increment an integer
    Function2();
  }
}
```

If you have many similar methods with same structure, then consider creating

```
private void DoSomething(Func<bool> condition, Action action)
{
    Function1();
    if (condition())
    {
        action();
        Function2();
    }
}
```

And invoke it this way:

```
private int value;

private void button2_Click()
{
    DoSomething(() => value < 5, () => value++);
}
```

Of course, if you need to pass some parameters to condition or action you should change `Func` or `Action` type. Also use `Func` instead of `Action` if you need to return some value from action.

```
private int value;

private void button2_Click()
{
    DoSomething((x) => x % 2 == 0, (x) =>  x.ToString());
}

private void DoSomething(Func<int, bool> condition, Func<int, string> action)
{
    Function1();
    if (condition(value))
    {
        string result = action(value);
        Function2();
    }
}
```

If your condition and action is not that simple, use named methods instead of lambdas:

```
private bool FooCondition(int x)
{
   // complex condition here
}

private string BarAction(int x)
{
    // complex action here
}

private void button2_Click()
{
    DoSomething(FooCondition, BarAction);
}
```

Comment: Function2 take some values from function1.

Comment: @user1340443 then just do not extract functions to methods. Or pass those values as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do this by wrapping condition 1 and condition 2 in methods and using them as a delegate, which allows them to be passed into a method.

For example, you could have the message with delegate signature expecting a method that takes x number of inputs and returns a boolean.  Then you create methods matching that signature for both condition 1 and 2, and pass the appropriate one in to the method.

Inside the method, you simply call the delegate as if it were a method (which, in actuality, it is).

Check Microsoft's documentation surrounding delegates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If these conditions are relatively simple, a [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) would probably be more readable that a separate method for each condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.0, you could pass a [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) to the method. Both classes which take parameters and no parameters exists.
A `Func` returning a boolean and a parameter, could be written with a lambda like this:

```
condition => {
  if (condition)
    index++;
  else
    index--;
}
```

The `Func` can be saved to a variable and passed around as wanted.