# Is there an easy way to implement C++ queries like the ones from ODB?

Tags: c++, filter, odb

I am working with filters in C++ and I would like to create a query like [ODB does:](https://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml#10.5)

db->query (query::age > 30)

I don't know what kind of data is being passed there. I have been reading about filters in C++ (with [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324023/passing-condition-as-parameter), lambda expressions, ...) but it is not as simple and compact as ODB queries. In addition, these query conditions can be concatenated.

db->query_one (query::first == "Joe" &&
query::last == "Dirt")

I have been looking what I think that [the query class code](https://git.codesynthesis.com/cgit/odb/libodb/tree/odb/query.hxx) is, but I have not been able to identify how it is achieved.

I need to filter a list of instances of Systems:

```cpp
class Model
{
  int id;
  QString name;
};
class System
{
  int id;
  int user_id;
  Model model;
};
```

I would like to have something like this:

```cpp
Filter<System> system_filter; 
Query<System> system_query(System::id == 1 && System::Model::name == "MyModelName")
system_filter.filter(system_list, system_query);
```

Currently I have this code (similar to an example of the book Design Patterns in Modern C++):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Specification
{
  virtual ~Specification(){}
  virtual bool is_specified(T* item) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Filter
{
  virtual QList<T*> filter(QList<T*> items, Specification<T>& spec)
  {
    QList<T*> result;
    for (auto& item:items)
    {
      if (spec.is_specified(item))
      {
        result.push_back(item);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
};
template <typename T>
struct IdSpecification: common::Specification<T>
{
  int id;

  IdSpecification(int id) : id(id){}

public:
  bool is_specified(T* item) override
  {
    return item->getId() == id;
  }
};
template <typename T>
struct NameSpecification: common::Specification<T>
{
  QRegularExpression regex;

  NameSpecification(const QRegularExpression& regex) : regex(regex){}

public:
  bool is_specified(T* item) override
  {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match(item->getName());
    return regex.match(item->getName()).hasMatch();
  }
};
template <typename T, typename B>
template <typename T>
struct AndSpecification: Specification<T>
{
  Specification<T>& first;
  Specification<T>& second;

  AndSpecification(Specification<T>& first, Specification<T>& second): first(first), second(second){}

public:
  bool is_specified(T* item) override
  {
    return first.is_specified(item) && second.is_specified(item);
  }
};
```

So now I can do something like this:

```cpp
IdSpecification<System> system_specification(3);
NameSpecification<System> name_specification("SytemName");
AndSpecification<System> and_specification(system_specification, type_specification);
auto system_filtered = system_filter.filter(system_list, and_specification);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is "C++ query" and on what data it acts? Can you give an example of input,output?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way. If ODB team managed to get syntax like that, it's probably some very advanced metaprogramming

Comment: You are quoting someone using `#pragma`s.  This means they modified the compiler to parse and use that -- there is no access to `#pragma` from "within" C++, it is all compiler extensions.  You could do something extremely fancy and get something somewhat similar, but it would be an abomination I suspect.

Comment: Quimby I included a more detailed explanation. Thank you @Yakk-AdamNevraumont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want expression trees.

You might start with:

```
template<auto Member>
struct member_query_t;

template<class T, class V>
struct member_query_t< V T::* M > {
  V const& operator()(T const& t) const { return t.*M; }
};
template<auto Member>
constexpr member_query_t<Member> member_q = {};
```

now `member_q<&Model::id>` is a C++ object that knows both what class it is operating on, and how to access the member `id`.

We can now build something called exprssion trees.  Here, we make some types and overload some operators to return a compile-time type with the information about the expression encoded in it.

We can augment this with an ordering, a hash, a comparison, and the like, so our store can see we are being queried for `Member` and store fast lookup information inside itself for `Member`.

```
template<class T, class V>
struct member_query_t< V T::* M > {
  V const& operator()(T const& t) const { return t.*M; }

  auto hasher() const {
    return std::hash<T>{};
  }
  auto ordering() const {
    return std::less<T>{};
  }
  auto comparison() const {
    return std::equal_to<T>{};
  }
};
```

you can get fancy to avoid requiring full specialization for those traits.  This kind of syntax would be possible:

```
auto system_query(
  member_query<&System::id> == 1 &&  
  member_query<&System::model>[member_query<&Model::name>] == "MyModelName"
);
```

where `system_query` has the entire process of how a lookup works stored its type.

We can then do a completely *different* advanced technique called type erasure in C++ to make this into a `Query<System>`.

Each of these is easily 100s of lines of relatively dense template code to get working right.

What more, even after you do that, writing `Filter<System>` to work requires delving into RTTI and writing an efficient generic database system that can handle nearly arbitrary lookup mechanisms and compose them together on request.

So you have like 3 hard challenges to do what you want to describe, any one of which would require me multiple iterated versions to get right.